# Hidden file in ruby

Tags: ruby, hidden-files

Can we create a hidden file using ruby?

Comment: What OS are we talking about?

Comment: Shouldn't that be just naming your file so that the name starts with a dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.open('/path/to/.hiddenfile', 'w') {|f| f.write(doc) }
```